# Deadlock while creating bean in DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry and CachingConnectionFactory

Tags: java, spring, deadlock, spring-amqp, spring-bean

My application finds deadlock while bean initialization. Two beans are waiting and holding resources required by one another in different threads. During the bean initialization "BeanA" class has taken lock of `"connectionMonitor"` object by calling method `[CachingConnectionFactory >> createConnection()]` and waiting for lock of ConcurrentHashMap `"singletonObjects"` in DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry. Whereas "BeanB" has taken lock of `ConcurrentHashMap "singletonObjects"` by calling method `[DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry >> getSingleton()]` and is waiting for lock of  "connectionMonitor" object in CachingConnectionFactory.

Thread dump :-

**Thread 1**:-

```
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:187)
- waiting to lock <0x000008001202c048> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isSingleton(AbstractBeanFactory.java:399)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:431)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:515)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1197)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.initialize(RabbitAdmin.java:457)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin$11.onCreate(RabbitAdmin.java:419)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CompositeConnectionListener.onCreate(CompositeConnectionListener.java:33)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:553)
- locked <0x000009fff2a3a620> (a java.lang.Object)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$1.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:90)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:140)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:76)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:496)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1331)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Thread 2**:-

```
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:544)
- waiting to lock <0x000009fff2a3a620> (a java.lang.Object)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1431)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1412)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1388)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.declareQueue(RabbitAdmin.java:207)
<some call stack lines removed from here for privacy>
- locked <0x000008001202c048> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
```

I am trying to establish connection to rabbit in the `@PostConstruct` method something like below:-

```java
BeanA {
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
      <call to CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection is made using some code)>
    }
}

BeanB {
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
      <call to CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection is made using some code)>
    }
}
```

Please suggest what needs to be done. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is too early to get access to low-level resources like connection from the initialization phase.

Consider to implement a `SmartLifecycle` and call that `createConnection()` from the `start()` implementation instead of that `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: Thanks Artem for help, I am implementing this approach and will accept as answer if it runs fine in my application setup :)